# CRUD (Update) Operation in Angular With API

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am new to angular and currently trying out CRUD operations using an API.

I have Two Components `ListPage` with an **Edit** Button and an `EditPage` with required `TextFields` to Edit my object. when i Click **Edit** function  `(click)="editItem(dataItem)` *(dataItem is the object i need to edit)* is called and the object is received in `ListComponent.ts`. So the Question is what code do I need to write inside

```js
editItem(item: any) {
   this.userToEdit = item;
}
```

to Open 'EditPage' with its `TextFields` Filled with  value from *editItem*
and What Do I Need to write inside `EditPage.Comonent.ts` To receive the data? Considering `editItem`
have the values `ID` and `Name` only.

**Name of Files in my Code is different from description**

EDIT PAGE HTML

```html
    <form >
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="UserNme" [(ngModel)]="USERNAME" name="c">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="PASSWORD" name="b">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="EMAIL" name="a">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button (click)="editUser()">
                EditUser
            </button >
        </div>
    </form>
```

EditPAge Compo.ts

```js
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-edit-page',
      templateUrl: './edit-page.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./edit-page.component.css']
    })
    export class EditPAgeComponent implements OnInit {
    
      USERNAME:string="";
      PASSWORD:string="";
      EMAIL:string="";
      ID:number=0;
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
      editUser() : void{
       if(this.ID!=0)
       {
    
       }
      }
    }
```

page 1 Component ie ListPAge

```html
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-1">UserName</th>
                    <th class="col-md-5">Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let dataItem of UserList">
                    <td>
                        {{dataItem.USERNAME}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{dataItem.EMAIL}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="deleteItem(dataItem.ID)">
                            Edit
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteItem(dataItem.ID)">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    
        </table>
    </div>
    <div hidden="false" class="container">
    
    </div>
```

and Page-1 component .ts ie ListPage.component.ts in dis

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
    import { AServiceService } from '../aservice.service';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-page-one',
      templateUrl: './page-one.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./page-one.component.css']
    })
    
    
    export class PageOneComponent implements OnInit {
    
      UserList: any = [];
      userToEdit: any;
      
      
      constructor(private ser: AServiceService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadUSerList();
      }
    
    
      editItem(item: any) {
        this.userToEdit = item;
      
      }
    
      deleteItem(item: number) {
        this.ser.deleteUser(item).subscribe(data => {
          alert(data.toString());
          this.loadUSerList();
        });
        this.ngOnInit();
      }
      closeClick() {
    
      }
      loadUSerList() {
        this.ser.getUsers().subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.UserList = data;
          console.log("LOG USERLIST");
        })
      }
    }
```

I Appreciate Any Help . Trying to learn angular

Comment: You can refer https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.

1. The most common way is to add the EditPage to your routes with a parameter

   { path: 'edit/:*', component: EditPageComponent },

pass the id as parameter and get the actual item from the service on the EditPage:

- Add the private route: ActivatedRoute, to your constructor parameters
- Get the parameter on nginit:

  this.route.params.subscribe((paramList: Params) => {
  if (paramList[ ' * ' ] === undefined) { this.id = 0; } else { this.id = paramList['*']; }

In this case your editItem(item) should be:

```
editItem(item: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['/edit/' + item.id + '']);
}
```

Of course you need to add the router to constructor:

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
) { }
```

It is safe to reload the page anytime, so it is a quite common scenario.

2. Pass the object as a navigation extra:

   editItem(item: any) {
   this.router.navigate(['/edit'], { state: { item: this.userToEdit }});
   }

It has a big down side: the user can not reload the edit page because it loose the passed object.

3. You can use popup editor (for example a mat_dialog) and pass the item to it.

   export class EditPageComponent {
   editItem(item: any) {
   const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
   dialogConfig.width = '570px';
   dialogConfig.height = '520px';
   dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
   dialogConfig.data = item;
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TigenyOtrotdComponent, dialogConfig);
   }

   constructor(
   private dialog: MatDialog,
   ) { }
   }
4. You can insert the component as an inline editor and specify the Editor inputs and outputs:

On EditPage.ts:

```
export class EditPageComponent {
    @Input() userToEdit: string;
    @Output() onSave: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

You can insert the editor anywhere (and make it visible or not with an ngif statement) in your list html:

```
<app-edit-user 
    [userToEdit]="userToEdit"
    (onSave)="hideEditor($event)"
>
</app-edit-user>
```

You can even make true inline editor if you list like that:

```
<ng-container *ngfor...>
<tr *ngif="!item.inEdit">
  ...readonly fields in td-s...
</tr>
<tr *ngif="item.inEdit">
  <app-edit-user [userToEdit]="item" (onSave)="item.inEdit = false"></app-edit-user>
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank You This seems to work. But currently i have found an alternate way ie #1 Created a new Service in `ListPage` with a **static object** and its get set methods . imported it in `EditPage`  and useed it to initilize the `EditPage`.